# How to divide the dataframe into bins of specific length with unequal number of points?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, binning

I have a dataframe and I want to divide that dataframe into bins of equal width (Number of data points in each bins may not be same). I have tried the following approach

```
df = pc13.sort_values(by = ['A'],  ascending=True)
df_temp = np.array_split(df, 20)
```

But this approach is dividing the dataframe into bins with equal number of data points. Instead of that I want to divide the dataframe into bins of particular width, also number of data points in each bin may not be same.

The minimum value in the dataframe column A is -0.04843731030699292 and maximum value is 0.05417013917000033. I tried uploading the entire dataframe but it is very big file.

Comment: Please share your dataframe too. Or at least the range of values of the column you want to bin.

Comment: @MohitMotwani I added the min and max value for the dataframe for which I'm trying to apply binning.

Comment: @Upriser what is the criteria for splitting into bins?

Comment: @Chris The bin width should be equal but the number of points in the bins can be different.

Comment: @Upriser your code above is just splitting your dataframe based on the index it has nothing to do with columns. The width is always going to be the same as the original dataframe

Comment: @Chris When I'm splitting the dataframe with above appraoch it divides the dataframe into bins with equal number of points in each bin instead of that I just need to divide the dataframe into equal width bins rather than equal number of points in those bins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
# create a random df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

# sort valeus
df = df.sort_values(by = ['A'],  ascending=True)

# use your code but on a transposed dataframe
new = np.array_split(df.T, 5) # split columns into 5 bins

# list comprehension to transposed dataframes
dfs = [new[i].T for i in range(len(new))]
```

## update

```
# random df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))

# sort on A
df.sort_values('A', inplace=True)

# create bins
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['A'], 20, include_lowest = True)

# group on bin
group = df.groupby('bin')

# list comprehension to split groups into list of dataframes 
dfs = [group.get_group(x) for x in group.groups]


[            A         B         C         D         E               bin
 218 -2.716093  0.833726 -0.771400  0.691251  0.162448  (-2.723, -2.413]
 207 -2.581388 -2.318333 -0.001467  0.035277  1.219666  (-2.723, -2.413]
 380 -2.499710  1.946709 -0.519070  1.653383  0.309689  (-2.723, -2.413]
 866 -2.492050  0.246500 -0.596392  0.872888  2.371652  (-2.723, -2.413]
 876 -2.469238 -0.156470 -0.841065 -1.248793 -0.489665  (-2.723, -2.413]
 314 -2.456308  0.630691 -0.072146  1.139697  0.663674  (-2.723, -2.413]
 310 -2.455353  0.075842  0.589515 -0.427233  1.207979  (-2.723, -2.413]
 660 -2.427255  0.890125 -0.042716 -1.038401  0.651324  (-2.723, -2.413],
             A         B         C         D         E              bin
 571 -2.355430  0.383794 -1.266575 -1.214833 -0.862611  (-2.413, -2.11]
 977 -2.354416 -1.964189  0.440376  0.028032 -0.181360  (-2.413, -2.11]
 83  -2.276908  0.288462  0.370555 -0.546359 -2.033892  (-2.413, -2.11]
 196 -2.213729 -1.087783 -0.592884  1.233886  1.051164  (-2.413, -2.11]
 227 -2.146631  0.365183 -0.095293 -0.882414  0.385117  (-2.413, -2.11]
 39  -2.136800 -1.150065  0.180182 -0.424071  0.040370  (-2.413, -2.11],
             A         B         C         D         E              bin
 104 -2.108961 -0.396602 -1.014224 -1.277124  0.001030  (-2.11, -1.806]
 360 -2.098928  1.093483  1.438421 -0.980215  0.010359  (-2.11, -1.806]
 530 -2.088592  1.043201 -0.522468  0.482176 -0.680166  (-2.11, -1.806]
 158 -2.062759  2.070387  2.124621 -2.751532  0.674055  (-2.11, -1.806]
 971 -2.053039  0.347577 -0.498513  1.917305 -1.746493  (-2.11, -1.806]
 658 -2.002482 -1.222292 -0.398816  0.279228 -1.485782  (-2.11, -1.806]
 90  -1.985261  3.499251 -2.089028  1.238524 -1.781089  (-2.11, -1.806]
 466 -1.973640 -1.609920 -1.029454  0.809143 -0.228893  (-2.11, -1.806]
 40  -1.966016 -1.479240 -1.564966 -0.310133  1.338023  (-2.11, -1.806]
 279 -1.943666  0.762493  0.060038  0.449159  0.244411  (-2.11, -1.806]
 204 -1.940045  0.844901 -0.343691 -1.144836  1.385915  (-2.11, -1.806]
 780 -1.918548  0.212452  0.225789  0.216110  1.710532  (-2.11, -1.806]
 289 -1.897438  0.847664  0.689778 -0.454152 -0.747836  (-2.11, -1.806]
 159 -1.848425  0.477726  0.391384 -0.477804  0.168160  (-2.11, -1.806],
. . .
```

Comment: This approach is not helping me. It is dividing the dataframe into bins but each bin is having same number of points. I need to divide it into equal width where number of points can be different. Instead of using array_split there should be some other method for this. I have tried this approach before.

Comment: @Upriser do something like `np.split(df[df.colums[:5]], [1,3,6])` and append the remaining columns

Comment: @Upriser I think I understand what you are looking for now. I was confused by your attempt using `array_split`. See update